# Where does the \n come from?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to test a string. I get the innerHTML, yet it has extra `u'\n` and `\n'`

```
AssertionError: u'\n<p><strong>Codul de Utilizator/Parola introduse nu sunt corecte!</strong></p>\n' != '<p><strong>Codul de Utilizator/Parola introduse nu sunt corecte!</strong></p>'
```

HTML from site

```
<div id="errorDiv1" class="error" style="display: block;">
   <p><strong>Codul de Utilizator/Codul introduse nu sunt corecte!</strong></p>
</div>
```

Code

```
        error = self.driver.find_element_by_id("errorDiv1").get_attribute('innerHTML')
        expected_error = '<p><strong>Codul de Utilizator/Parola introduse nu sunt corecte!</strong></p>'
        self.assertEqual(error, expected_error)
```

What is happening here? Where they come from?

Comment: Trailing new line.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the new line character.

It's present since there's a new line character between line 1 and line 2 of your HTML code.

Comment: is there a way to remove this, easily?

Comment: `error.strip()` returns the value of `error` *sans* leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @user9485152: You can also remove the new lines in the HTML div.

Comment: @user9485152 Can you at least explain what it is exactly that you don't like?

Comment: i think innerHTML should return the html without any \n\r or whatever

Comment: @user9485152 innerHTML will return *exactly* what's there. If you had `<pre>This is some text</pre>`, you would want to have the possible `\n` in there. What if you had `<div>\n<div>\n<pre>Text</pre>\n</div>\n</div>` and you asked for the outer div's innerHTML? Which `\n` would you remove? All of them? Only the ones outside the `<pre>` . It doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: @user9485152 Whether you like it or not, newlines *are part of the inner HTML.* Newlines are text content and text content is part of the content of an HTML element; if `innerHTML` didn't return the newlines, then *it wouldn't be returning the inner HTML.*

Answer (score 0):

`u''` defines a Unicode String in python [Unicode Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings).

`'\n'` is a escape sequence and stands for [Linefeed](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html). Linefeed means advancing the printing area by one line.